# Rename layer result from PyQGIS QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT to something else

Tags: pyqgis, layers

I have a PyQGIS script that I exported from a QGIS process model.  I have set output layer names that make sense in the model but when I export and run the model in PyQGIS it outputs the temporary names eg: "Centroid", "Refactor" etc. rather than the layer names I set in original model.

How can I get the PyQGIS  to export to a QGIS canvas layer that I stipulate?

```
QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
```

---

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class BcPolygonReport(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('countyregion', 'County / Region (county_region_bc)', optional=True, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='County / Region (county_region_bc)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('crownlandleasesandpermitstacrtsvwpolygon', 'Crown Land Leases and Permits (ta_crt_svw_polygon)', optional=True, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='Crown Land Leases and Permits (ta_crt_svw_polygon)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('crownlandrightsofway', 'Crown Land Rights-of-Way', optional=True, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='Crown Land Rights-of-Way (ta_crw_svw_polygon)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('forestcoverreserve', 'Results Forest Cover Reserve', optional=True, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='Results Forest Cover Reserve (rslt_fcres_polygon)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('forestharvestauthorizationsftnhasvwpolygon', 'Forest Harvest Authorizations (ftn_ha_svw_polygon)', optional=True, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='Forest Harvest Authorizations (ftn_ha_svw_polygon)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('foresttenurecutblocksftncbplpolygon', 'Forest Tenure Cut Blocks (ftn_c_b_pl_polygon)', optional=True, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='Forest Tenure Cut Blocks (ftn_c_b_pl_polygon)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('foresttenureroadsegment', 'Forest Tenure Access', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine], defaultValue='Forest Tenure Access (ften_rs_ln_line)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('foresttenurespecialaccessroad', 'Forest Tenure Special Access Road', optional=True, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='Forest Tenure Special Access Road (ftn_s_ac_r_polygon)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('foresttenuretimberlicense', 'Forest Tenure Timber License', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='Forest Tenure Timber License (ften_tl_py_polygon)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('guideoutfitterboundary', 'Guide_Outfitter (waagoa_svw_polygon)', optional=True, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='Guide_Outfitter (waagoa_svw_polygon)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('mineralandcoaltitles', 'Mineral and Coal Titles', optional=True, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='Mineral and Coal Titles (mta_acq_te_polygon)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('pmbc', 'PMBC', optional=True, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='pmbc_unique_merged'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('rangetenure', 'Range Tenure (ftn_rng_py_polygon)', optional=True, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='Range Tenure (ftn_rng_py_polygon)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('resultsopeningsrsltopngspolygon', 'Results Openings (rslt_opngs_polygon)', optional=True, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='Results Openings (rslt_opngs_polygon)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('tantalussurveyedparcels', 'Tantalus Surveyed Parcels', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='Tantalis Surveyed Parcels (ta_sp_svw_polygon_)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('tantalussurveyedrightofway', 'Tantalus Surveyed Right-of-Way', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='Tantalus Surveyed Right-of-Way (ta_srp_svw_polygon)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('trapperboundary', 'Trappers (waatrp_ars_polygon)', optional=True, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='Trappers (waatrp_ars_polygon)'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('wellcentre', 'Polygon Set', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Reportpmbc', 'Report-PMBC', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('ReportrangesAndAreas', 'Report-Ranges and Areas', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('ReportmergedForestryTenures', 'Report-Merged Forestry Tenures', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('ReportrightsofwayAndLeases', 'Report-Rights-of-Way and Leases', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('ReportresultsForestTenureRoadSegments', 'Report-Results Forest Tenure Road Segments', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(50, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Extract Forest Tenure Access
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['foresttenureroadsegment'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': 0,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractForestTenureAccess'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Mineral and Coal Titles
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['mineralandcoaltitles'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': 0,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractMineralAndCoalTitles'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Trapper
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['trapperboundary'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': 0,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractTrapper'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Tantalus Surveyed Parcels
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['tantalussurveyedparcels'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': [0],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractTantalusSurveyedParcels'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract PMBC
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['pmbc'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': 0,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractPmbc'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(5)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Harvest Auth
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['forestharvestauthorizationsftnhasvwpolygon'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': 0,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractHarvestAuth'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(6)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Forest Tenure Special Access Road
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['foresttenurespecialaccessroad'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': 0,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractForestTenureSpecialAccessRoad'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(7)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Refactor Trapper
        alg_params = {
            'FIELDS_MAPPING': [{'expression': '', 'length': 4, 'name': 'Map Number', 'precision': 0, 'type': 2}, {'expression': "'Trapper ID.'", 'length': 56, 'name': 'Source', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'case\r\nwhen "trpln_iden" is null\r\nthen \'None\'\r\nwhen "trpln_iden" = \'\'\r\nthen \'None\'\r\nElse "trpln_iden"\r\nend', 'length': 24, 'name': 'Gov. ID No.', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': "'B.C. Trapper Assoc.'", 'length': 255, 'name': 'Description', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '', 'length': 56, 'name': 'Owner / Holder', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}],
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractTrapper']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['RefactorTrapper'] = processing.run('qgis:refactorfields', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(8)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Crown Land Rights-of-Way
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['crownlandrightsofway'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': [0],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractCrownLandRightsofway'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(9)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Crown Land Leases and Permits
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['crownlandleasesandpermitstacrtsvwpolygon'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': [0],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractCrownLandLeasesAndPermits'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(10)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Range / Tenure
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['rangetenure'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': 0,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractRangeTenure'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(11)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Crown Land Leases and Permits
        alg_params = {
            'EXPRESSION': '\"ten_type\" = \'INVENTORY\'\r\nor\r\n\"ten_type\" = \'LEASE\'\r\nor\r\n\"ten_type\" = \'PERMIT\'\r\nor\r\n\"ten_type\" = \'RIGHT-OF-WAY\'\r\nor\r\n\"ten_type\"=\'RESERVE/NOTATION\'\r\nor\r\n\"ten_type\"=\'LICENCE\'\r\n',
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractCrownLandLeasesAndPermits']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractCrownLandLeasesAndPermits'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(12)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Refactor Mineral and Coal Titles
        alg_params = {
            'FIELDS_MAPPING': [{'expression': '', 'length': 4, 'name': 'Map Number', 'precision': 0, 'type': 2}, {'expression': "'Mineral Coal Titles'", 'length': 56, 'name': 'Source', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"tnrnmbrd"', 'length': 24, 'name': 'Gov. ID No.', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"tnrtpdscrp"', 'length': 255, 'name': 'Description', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"owner_name"', 'length': 56, 'name': 'Owner / Holder', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}],
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractMineralAndCoalTitles']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['RefactorMineralAndCoalTitles'] = processing.run('qgis:refactorfields', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(13)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Results Openings
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['resultsopeningsrsltopngspolygon'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': 0,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractResultsOpenings'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(14)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Forest Tenure Timber License
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['foresttenuretimberlicense'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': 0,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractForestTenureTimberLicense'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(15)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract County / Region
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['countyregion'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': 0,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractCountyRegion'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(16)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Guide / Outfitter
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['guideoutfitterboundary'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': 0,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractGuideOutfitter'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(17)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Results Forest Cover Reserve
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['forestcoverreserve'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': 0,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractResultsForestCoverReserve'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(18)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Tantalus Parcel Subdivisions
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD': 'prcltp',
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractTantalusSurveyedParcels']['OUTPUT'],
            'OPERATOR': 0,
            'VALUE': 'Subdivision',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractTantalusParcelSubdivisions'] = processing.run('native:extractbyattribute', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(19)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Forest Tenure
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['foresttenurecutblocksftncbplpolygon'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': 0,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractForestTenure'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(20)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract by Tantalus Surveyed Right-of-Way
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['tantalussurveyedrightofway'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['wellcentre'],
            'PREDICATE': [0],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractByTantalusSurveyedRightofway'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(21)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Refactor Tantalus Surveyed Parcels
        alg_params = {
            'FIELDS_MAPPING': [{'expression': '"prcllgldsc"', 'length': 255, 'name': 'prcllgldsc', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}],
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractTantalusParcelSubdivisions']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['RefactorTantalusSurveyedParcels'] = processing.run('qgis:refactorfields', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(22)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Refactor Forest Road Segment
        alg_params = {
            'FIELDS_MAPPING': [{'expression': '', 'length': 4, 'name': 'Map Number', 'precision': 0, 'type': 2}, {'expression': "'Forest Tenure Road Segment'", 'length': 56, 'name': 'Source', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"ffid"', 'length': 24, 'name': 'Gov. ID No.', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': ' "life_st_cd"', 'length': 255, 'name': 'Description', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"rd_sect_nm"', 'length': 56, 'name': 'Owner / Holder', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}],
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractForestTenureAccess']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['ReportresultsForestTenureRoadSegments']
        }
        outputs['RefactorForestRoadSegment'] = processing.run('qgis:refactorfields', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['ReportresultsForestTenureRoadSegments'] = outputs['RefactorForestRoadSegment']['OUTPUT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(23)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}
```

Comment: Try this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/459464/172108
By the way, have you tried running all those intersects in a loop, just changing the input parameter and output name?

Answer (score 3):

Not to struggle with all those classes, language dependencies and changes to the api, I use following since QGIS 2.x (console):

```
class myProcessing(QObject):
    def __init__(self, cmd, parameters):
        super(myProcessing, self).__init__()
        try:
            self.layer=None
            self.prj=QgsProject.instance()
            self.prj.layerWasAdded.connect(self.layer_added)
            processing.runAndLoadResults(cmd,parameters)
            self.prj.layerWasAdded.disconnect(self.layer_added)
        except Exceptions as e:
            print(e)
            self.prj.layerWasAdded.disconnect(self.layer_added)

    def layer_added(self,layer):
        self.layer=layer

input_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('lines')[0]  
cmd="grass7:v.parallel"
parameters ={'distance':20,'side':1,'output':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
parameters['input']=QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(input_layer.name(), True)
proc=myProcessing(cmd,parameters)
out_layer=proc.layer
print(out_layer.name())
```