# Customizing QgsProcessing output layer name

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'M writing an own QgsProcessing Algorithm and I want to give the output layer in the registry a custom name instead of the default "Output layer". I want to do that during `processAlgorithm()`, because I'd like to name the output after an input layer, adding a fixed name prefix.

I tried the `setOutputLayerName()` from the class [`QgsProcessingContext::LayerDetails`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingContext_1_1LayerDetails.html#ad449e581e166692814c36aaa27ceabf9), but it doesn't change the name of the output. The example below is the "template" that the QGIS processing toolbox suggests for algorithm writing. Note the last third last and second last rows of the code, where I tried out my approach.

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsVectorLayer,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink)
from qgis import processing


class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
  
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return 'myscript'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('My Script')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Example scripts')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'examplescripts'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Example algorithm short description")

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output layer')
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        source = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT,
            context
        )

        
        if source is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSourceError(parameters, self.INPUT))

        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
            parameters,
            self.OUTPUT,
            context,
            source.fields(),
            source.wkbType(),
            source.sourceCrs()
        )

        # Send some information to the user
        feedback.pushInfo('CRS is {}'.format(source.sourceCrs().authid()))

        if sink is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSinkError(parameters, self.OUTPUT))

        
        total = 100.0 / source.featureCount() if source.featureCount() else 0
        features = source.getFeatures()

        for current, feature in enumerate(features):
            # Stop the algorithm if cancel button has been clicked
            if feedback.isCanceled():
                break

            # Add a feature in the sink
            sink.addFeature(feature, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)

            # Update the progress bar
            feedback.setProgress(int(current * total))

        if False:
            buffered_layer = processing.run("native:buffer", {
                'INPUT': dest_id,
                'DISTANCE': 1.5,
                'SEGMENTS': 5,
                'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
                'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
                'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
                'DISSOLVE': False,
                'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
            }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']

        layer = QgsVectorLayer(baseName="My Output") # Create an empty layer for output naming
        context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(dest_id).setOutputLayerName(layer) # Add this name to the output context
        return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the `QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface.postProcessLayer` method to rename the layer after it has been added to the project. Using the `QgsMapLayer.setName` method has no effect. To use this, define a new class:

```
class Renamer (QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface):
    def __init__(self, layer_name):
        self.name = layer_name
        super().__init__()
        
    def postProcessLayer(self, layer, context, feedback):
        layer.setName(self.name)
```

Then in your code, create an instance of the class and attach it to the output layer:

```
    global renamer
    renamer = Renamer('DiffBuf')
    context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(self.dest_id).setPostProcessor(renamer)
```

It is essential that you declare the variable holding the class as `global`, otherwise this will not work. `self.dest_id` in the code is the value of the second return value of `parameterAsSink`.

Answer (score 1):

I figure out you can just do :

```
layer_details = context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(dest_id)
layer_details.name = "My output"
```

To remove the error in log (if the layer is not loaded) it's possible to do this :

```
if context.willLoadLayerOnCompletion(dest_id):
    layer_details = context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(dest_id)
    layer_details.name = "My output"
```