# Rename the resulting layer of a QGIS model within the same script with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler, rename

At the end of my processing model, it runs an "Add geometry attributes" operation. I want the **resulting layer to be named "Overlap" instead of the default "Added geom info."** How should I insert the renaming process in the same script?

This is the **start** of the model

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(4, feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}
```

This is the **end** of the model

```
alg_params = {
            'CALC_METHOD': 0,
            'INPUT': outputs['DissolveOverlap']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['MeasuredOverlap']
        }
        results['MeasuredOverlap'] = processing.run('qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        return results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@[Llaves](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/385009/146811) provided the solution. Anyway, add this class first

```
class Renamer (QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface):
    def __init__(self, layer_name):
        self.name = layer_name
        super().__init__()
        
    def postProcessLayer(self, layer, context, feedback):
        layer.setName(self.name)
```

Then add this before you return 'results'

```
global renamer
renamer = Renamer('test')
context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(results['MeasuredOverlap']['OUTPUT']).setPostProcessor(renamer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and shortest solution is by [lejedi76](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30274/lejedi76) in an answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/459464/172108):

```
layer_id = results['MeasuredOverlap']['OUTPUT']
layer_details = context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(layer_id)
layer_details.name = "My name is Overlap"
```

To be used just before returning results.